# This or These? Nor or Or?

Tags: grammar, or-nor

I'm not really sure about my grammar, and I think I need help. I'm a bit confused with the "These" and "This", and the "Nor" or "Or". My wedding is in a few hours and I just finished composing my vow. Here's my vow:

My love, you are my only best friend, the best friend that I've ever had. I promise you **these**:

- I won't do things that will make you mad, make you sad, and most importantly, things that will break your heart.
- I won't fight you as much as possible, I will try to understand you first.
- You can count on me every single time. I will be your best friend forever no matter what happens.
- I will respect you, I won't hurt you emotionally **nor** physically.
- Lastly, I will love you forever, until the Lord take my life here on Earth.

I would greatly appreciate if you can point out to me as well the wrong grammars here. Thanks!

Comment: Congratulations on your nuptials. We don't really do this sort of correction, but since it's a special occasion... I'd use *this* because it's all one promise (and "I promise you this" is rather a set phrase). And it should be *or* because you already have a negative in *won't*. If you want *nor* then it would have to be "I will hurt you neither emotionally nor physically," and while people will prick up their ears at "I will hurt you", you might not want that to happen, even if you then say *neither...nor*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the senior member Andrew Leach so kindly corrected, making a special exception for a special occasion, it should be

> "I promise you **this**..." and
>
> "...I won't hurt you emotionally **or** physically."

MAY I ALSO SUGGEST that "I won't fight you as much as possible" does not sound quite right, though your meaning is clear: you could try to reposition 'as much as possible' and put it as

> I won't fight **with you**, but will try to understand you first, as much as possible.

The rest of it is just fine!

Comment: Or even just move the punctuation: "I won't fight you; as much as possible, I will try to understand you first." But that does change the meaning slightly.

Comment: @Andrew Leach you are right, of course; I did consider just changing the punctuation,  but remembered that she might intend to 'recite' her vows, in which case the slightest ambiguity might creep in.

Comment: Andrew Leach made a special exception, but also preserved site integrity by not responding in an 'answer'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Of course I may be mistaken, but I am respectfully not convinced about your interpretation that Andrew Leach chose 'not to respond in an answer' in order to 'preserve site integrity.' Since the senior member has already made a special exception, I think OP's question can be given an answer, but you may disagree. It is nice to see that we take ourselves SO seriously here, but I am only an ignorant new person, and nowadays afraid to post an answer! If you consider it necessary in your learned opinion, you can kindly vote to close the question as off-topic and I will vote with you.

Comment: Why do you think Andrew restricted his response to a 'comment' (which may well disappear from the archives)? Is copying a 'comment' as an answer within the spirit of the site?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth my answer was fully and transparently attributed to Andrew Leach who originally gave the answer in comments. I am ignorant of these fine points of difference and am grateful to you for enlightening me, but feel that my giving a fully attributed answer to OP's question after Andrew Leach had graciously made a special exception does **not** in anyway compromise the 'spirit' or 'integrity' of this great website.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth since you are so concerned about whether this question and answer are appropriate, you should consider migrating the question to ELL if it meets the criteria, or else close it as off topic. Kindly do not take it personally, and **I do request you to excuse my sharp reply**, but I just do not understand the need for such a rigid approach when even more nonsensical questions are routinely being asked and answered here at EL&U.

Comment: 'We don't really do this sort of correction' means 'off-topic on ELU' + 'I'll answer in a 'comment' which helps you out on this special occasion but doesn't invite duplicate off-topic questions pleading preferential treatment, thus attempting to make / keep this website great'. // I trust you close-vote 'even more nonsensical questions [which] are routinely being asked and answered here at EL&U'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth thank you for the explanation. I fully understand your concern for the site and agree that we need to look out for the quality of questions and answers here. I mean no disrespect and appreciate your point of view. I shall be very careful not to answer 'such questions' in future!